# How to get the length of the array from a promise?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a function returning the promise of an array:

```
movementListOfTheUserForTheStockCode(userID: string): Promise<calculatedMovement[]>
```

### How to get the length of the array?

How to assign a promising function into a constant?

```js
const  movementList = movementListOfTheUserForTheStockCode(userID);
for (let i = 0; i < rawMovementList.length; i++) {
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling this async method you won't get the actual Array instance, but the Promise of the array.
So to get the actual array instance you should await for the promise:

```js
async someAsyncFunction () {
   const  rawMovementList = await rawMovementListOfTheUserForTheStockCode(userID, code);
   for (let i = 0; i < rawMovementList.length; i++) {
      // do stuff
   }
}
```

or using it by the older way with `then` approach.

```js
rawMovementListOfTheUserForTheStockCode(userID, code).then(rawMovementList => {
    for (let i = 0; i < rawMovementList.length; i++) {
      // do stuff
   }
})
```